# Get formatted string from Calendar

Tags: java, date, formatdatetime

I've got a `Calendar` Date in Java.

I need to convert it in a `String` with this format :

```
2020-12-29T00:00:00+01:00
```

How can I do it?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I've got a Calendar Date in Java"?

Comment: *I've got a `Calendar` Date in Java.* Avoid that if there’s any way you can. The `Calendar` class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the `Date` object by calling [`Calendar#getTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime()) and format it using a [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with the format, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX`.

**Note:** Since the desired string has timezone offset of `+01:00` hours, make sure you set the timezone of the `SimpleDateFormat` object to `TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1")` before calling `SimpleDateFormat#format`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1"));
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        String formatted = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Another example:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String dateTimeString = "2020-12-29T00:00:00+01:00";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
        Date obj = sdf.parse(dateTimeString);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(obj);

        // Formatting this calendar object
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1"));
        String formatted = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-29T00:00:00+01:00
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  The first example return an exception, but the second one work perfectly.

Comment: @Mauraglia - You are most welcome. I have checked the first example again and it works fine. The only thing is that it creates a `Calendar` object for the current date-time which I chose intentionally for the demonstration. You can check [this](https://ideone.com/vqBfxV) if you are interested. Anyway, I'm glad that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

Here’s a formatter for your desired format:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
```

With this we may do:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Barnaul");
    ZonedDateTime dateTime
            = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.DECEMBER, 29).atStartOfDay(zone);
    String formatted = dateTime.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(formatted);
```

Output from this example snipoet is:

> 2020-12-29T00:00:00+07:00

### If you cannot avoid getting a Calendar

If you are getting a `Calendar` object from a legacy API that you cannot afford to upgrade to java.time just now, convert it to `ZonedDateTime`. It is almost certainly really a `GregorianCalendar` (or formatting into that format would not make much sense), which makes the conversion straightforward.

```
    Calendar yourCalendar = getCalendarFromLegacyApi();
    ZonedDateTime dateTime
            = ((GregorianCalendar) yourCalendar).toZonedDateTime();
```

The rest is as before, as is the output.

If you need to take into account the possibility that the `Calendar` is not a `GregorianCalendar`, use this slightly more complicated conversion instead:

```
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = yourCalendar.toInstant()
            .atZone(yourCalendar.getTimeZone().toZoneId());
```

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.